# Dynamically loaded javascript works sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I load this javascript file dynamically in the `<head/>` of my document like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
    if (window.screen.width <= 1600)
    {
        console.log("start");
        var jsref1 = document.createElement('script');
        jsref1.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        jsref1.setAttribute("src", "/javascript/mobileFunction.js");         
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(jsref1);                       
    }
    console.log(end)
</script>
```

In my all my javascript file I have this custom event called which is at the end of `$(document).ready`

```
$(document).on("xsltready", function () {
  ...more code....       
   console.log("event alled here " + a variable);
```

The problem is that I see the output for the two console from the dynamically loaded javascript and when I check the resource folder under the script folder in web-inpector(I am using mobile safari and remote web inspector) the file is there. The problem is that sometimes when I refresh the page it looks like the file is not loaded since none of the `console.log()` from inside the script is executed and. But if I refresh a few times again it comes back. Is this a behavior with loading javascript dynamically?

**Note**

I can still call the method inside the dynamically loaded JS file, but the custom event I trigger at the end of `$(document).ready` is not executed at all.

Comment: Hello you need to write your code inside a function. how can you write it openly even if it is written inside <script>. you need to define everything inside function.

Comment: define these inside a function  as function myfun() { if (window.screen.width <= 1600)
    {
        console.log("start");
        var jsref1 = document.createElement('script');
        jsref1.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        jsref1.setAttribute("src", "/javascript/mobileFunction.js");         
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(jsref1);                       
    }
    console.log(end); }

Comment: `$(document).ready` is probably firing before the script has loaded. You are adding the script asynchronously, and hence the DOM does not wait for the script to load, before it is ready.

Comment: @kumarch1 I tied doing as you suggested and the same effect is still happening. After a few refresh the custom event is not called. Although the hint putting the code inside a function is good.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Levi, *his comment is above* he helped me go in the right direction. He was correct in that the the `$(docuemnt).ready` is fired before the script has loaded. *the DOM does not wait for the script to load, before it is ready.* ~ Levi. So what I did was instead of firing my custom event in the `$(docuemnt).load` it is fired in the `$(window).load` event, which solve the problem. But now I have a performance issue.